# how to add multiple command bindings in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, commandbinding

I am working with WPF. I want to create keyboard shortcuts for my WPF application. I have created as following. The first command binding tag for "*open*" is working and command binding for exit is not working. I dont know what is the reason.

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding Command="Open" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
<CommandBinding Command="Exit" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_1" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
<KeyBinding Command="Open" Key="O" Modifiers="control" />
<KeyBinding Command="Exit" Key="E" Modifiers="control"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Above code is getting the following error:

*Cannot convert string 'Exit' in attribute 'Command' to object of type 
'System.Windows.Input.ICommand'. CommandConverter cannot convert from 
System.String. Error at object 'System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding' in 
 markup file 'WpfApplication2;component/window1.xaml' Line 80 Position 25.*

Comment: Can you also supply the actual code and xaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that there is no exit command. You'll have to roll your own.

[See here for built-in ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx)

It's pretty easy to create your own, I use a static utility class to hold common commands that I use often. Something like this:

```
public static class AppCommands
{
    private static RoutedUICommand exitCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Exit","Exit", typeof(AppCommands));

    public static RoutedCommand ExitCommand
    {
        get { return exitCommand; }
    }

    static AppCommands()
    {
        CommandBinding exitBinding = new CommandBinding(exitCommand);
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(AppCommands), exitBinding);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to bind it like this:

```
<KeyBinding Command="{x:Static local:AppCommands.Exit}" Key="E" Modifiers="control"/>
```

Comment: @havan: Well, there are several sets of commands already built into .NET. There's a set of ComponentCommands, MediaCommands, NavigationCommands and EditingCommands. But it's easy to create your own commands. I've edited my answer to show one way of doing it. Also, I have no idea why Microsoft neglected to add an ExitCommand to ApplicationCommands.